# Limit what a tethered iPhone internet connection can be used for

Tags: mac, network, wifi, cellular-data, tethering

I have various background services running on my Mac which use quite a lot of bandwidth: Google Drive, a couple of OneDrive sync programs, iCloud sync, Dropbox, and Backblaze for a general backup of my harddrive.

This is fine when I'm on a regular wifi connection, but when i tether my Mac to my iPhone I have limited data -- only 4GB per month. I'd like to be able to limit the services which can use my internet connection when that internet connection is provided by my iPhone.

Is there a straightforward way to do this? I use Little Snitch and think I might be able to set up a specific profile for when I've connected via a tethered iPhone, but this seems quite complicated.

Comment: I know this comment is not very helpful on a Mac forum, but Windows 10 has an option for Metered connection.


Macs would also know if you are on an iPhone Tether, and I am sure things like "Metered Connection" will soon be standard on various Operating Systems.


With luck, third party applications will start respecting such indications.


When I tether my phone, I can get through data so quickly, it is unbelievable.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and have been using "Trip Mode" on my Mac to good use. Currently sells for about $10CAD.

http://tripmode.ch

What I need now is something that will do the same on my iPad...